# rails array of hashes calculate one column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array and it has many columns and I want to change one value of my one column.

My array is:

```
  [
    {
    id: 1,
    Districts: "Lakhisarai",
    Area: 15.87,
    Production: 67.77,
    Productivity: 4271,
    Year: 2015,
    Area_Colour: "Red",
    Production_Colour: "Orange",
    Productivity_Colour: "Dark_Green",
    created_at: "2018-07-24T11:24:13.000Z",
    updated_at: "2018-07-24T11:24:13.000Z"
    },
    {
    id: 29,
    Districts: "Begusarai",
    Area: 18.53,
    Production: 29.35,
    Productivity: 1584,
    Year: 2015,
    Area_Colour: "Red",
    Production_Colour: "Red",
    Productivity_Colour: "Orange",
    created_at: "2018-07-24T11:24:13.000Z",
    updated_at: "2018-07-24T11:24:13.000Z"
    },
    ...
]
```

This is my sample array and I want my Productivity to be divided by 100 for that I am using one empty array and pushing these hashes to my array like:

```
 j = []
b.map do |k|
  if k.Productivity
    u = k.Productivity/100
    j.push({id: k.id, Productivity: u })
  else
    j.push({id: k.id, Productivity: k.Productivity })
  end
```

Is there any simple way where I can generate this kind of array and reflect my changes to to one column. Is there any way where I don't need to push name of column one by one in push method.

I want to generate exact same array with one modification in productivity

Comment: b is the array I am mapping

Comment: Is your code working? How do you access a key of hash using dot notation e.g. `k.Productivity`?

Comment: yes that is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say your array is `e`, then:

```
e.each { |item| item[:Productivity] = item[:Productivity]/100}
```

Example:

```
e = [{p: 12, d: 13}, {p:14, d:70}]

e.each { |item| item[:p] = item[:p]/10}
```

**output:** `[{:p=>1, :d=>13}, {:p=>1, :d=>70}]`

Comment: what if I want to put condition if productivity is there in array

Comment: @NlaySingh you can put unless condition like this `e.each { |item| item[:p] = item[:p]/10 unless p.blank? }`

Comment: is it possible to do with map

Answer (score 0):

You could take help of [map](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map) method here to create a new array from your original array, but with the mentioned changes.

```
ary.map do |elem|
  h = elem.slice(:id)
  h[:productivity] = elem[:Productivity] / 100 if elem[:Productivity]
  h
end
 => [{:id=>1, :productivity=>42}, {:id=>29, :productivity=>15}]
```

Note, [Hash#slice](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice) returns a new hash with only the key-value pairs for the keys passed in argument e.g. here, it returns `{ id: 1 }` for first element.

Also, we are assigning the calculated productivity to the output only when it is set on original hash. Hence, the `if` condition there.

Comment: Good point. I thought it was self-explanatory. Updated it anyway. :)